Error E0307: Invalid self Parameter Type in Rust Method with Rc<RefCell>
I am writing the following code in Rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    parent: Option<Weak<RefCell<Node>>>,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
impl Node {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            value,
            parent: None,
            children: Vec::new(),
        }))
    }
    fn add_child(self: Rc<RefCell<Node>>, child: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
        self.borrow_mut().children.push(Rc::clone(&child));
        child.borrow_mut().parent = Some(Rc::downgrade(&self));
    }
}

However, the add_child() method does not compile. I get the following error:
error[E0307]: invalid `self` parameter type: Rc<RefCell<Node>>
  --> src/main.rs:18:24
   |
18 |     fn add_child(self: Rc<RefCell<Self>>, child: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type of `self` must be `Self` or a type that dereferences to it
   = help: consider changing to `self`, `&self`, `&mut self`, `self: Box<Self>`, `self: Rc<Self>`, `self: Arc<Self>`, or `self: Pin<P>` (where P is one of the previous types except `Self`)

I want to call the method directly on a Rc<RefCell<Node>> object, which is returned by Node::new(). And I don't want to use Box unless it is necessary. What would be the correct signature for add_child() method?

You can't do this, as the compiler explains:

type of `self` must be `Self` or a type that dereferences to it


RefCell<T> does not deref to T.  Doing so would make borrowing the contents of the RefCell implicit instead of explicit, which would make it substantially more difficult to reason about where borrows happen, and therefore where a panic might happen.
Consider instead taking &mut self.
Alternatively, you can use traits to effectively add methods to arbitrary types.  This makes your crate harder to understand, so I would strongly suggest not doing this, but it's still a useful pattern to know about.
trait AddChild {
    fn add_child(self, child: Self);
}

impl AddChild for Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
    fn add_child(self, child: Self) {
        self.borrow_mut().children.push(Rc::clone(&child));
        child.borrow_mut().parent = Some(Rc::downgrade(&self));
    }
}

Now you can call .add_child directly on an Rc<RefCell<Node>> as long as AddChild is in scope.

Alternatively, wrap the Rc<RefCell> in a custom type.
